# SQL If two records exist, choose which one you want to display Teradata

Tags: sql, olap, teradata

Sorry for the poor title/description. What is happening is I'm joining to another table by ID but the data is coming from two different admin systems (CLONE and GRASN) Is there any code I can add to say "if CLONE and GRASN exist, use CLONE"?

a simple query looks like this:

```
 ` select sorce_claim_id
  ,claim_sorce_syst_cd
  ,sorce_agrmt_id
  ,asgn_sorce_syst_cd
  from edw_p.claim_agrmt
  where sorce_claim_id = '4513049'`
```

and is returning the following:

```
    SORCE_CLAIM_ID  CLAIM_SORCE_SYST_CD SORCE_AGRMT_ID  ASGN_SORCE_SYST_CD
4513049             NVLNK              00932419       GRASN
4513049             NVLNK              R0035600       CLONE
```

I would like only to pull the second record. I can't just say WHERE ASGN_SORCE_SYST_CD = CLONE as that will bring only the clones back. The table basically consists of mostly GRASN but there are duplicate records (like in this case) where if there are, I want to use the CLONE record.

I hope this makes enough sense. I'm working in Teradata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  sorce_claim_id
        ,claim_sorce_syst_cd
        ,sorce_agrmt_id
        ,asgn_sorce_syst_cd
from    edw_p.claim_agrmt
where   sorce_claim_id = '4513049'
and     asgn_sorce_syst_cd = 'CLONE'
UNION
select  sorce_claim_id
        ,claim_sorce_syst_cd
        ,sorce_agrmt_id
        ,asgn_sorce_syst_cd
from    edw_p.claim_agrmt
where   sorce_claim_id = '4513049'
and     asgn_sorce_syst_cd = 'GRASN'
and     source_claim_id NOT IN (select sorce_claim_id from edw_p.claim_agrmt where asgn_sorce_syst_cd = 'CLONE')
```

Comment: I think `sorce_claim_id = '4513049' and (asgn_sorce_syst_cd = 'CLONE' or source_claim_id NOT IN (select sorce_claim_id from edw_p.claim_agrmt where asgn_sorce_syst_cd = 'CLONE'))` would be simpler and sufficient, but +1 anyway, you should still get the right results with your query.

Comment: I suggest changing the not in to either a not exists or and source_claim_id in (select foo minus select bar), depending on what syntax teradata supports.  Not in tends to be slow.